# overridePendingTransition, Animation works in one instance but not in another?

Tags: java, android, animation, overriding, transition

FloatingActionButton clicked in MainActivity. Now GroupsPage slides up over MainActivity. Regular button clicked in GroupsPage, now GroupsPage slides down revealing MainActivity.

**Issue**=When GroupsPage slides down revealing MainActivity, the animation transition for sliding down is too fast, so fast that the animation downward is barely visible.

Here's my code:
MainActivity = Floating Action Button  takes you to GroupsPage: Slide Up Animation

```
final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GroupsPage.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);



   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animate_up, R.anim.no_anim);



        }
    });
```

**^** Animation sliding up works fine.

In GroupsPage, it has button, back to MainActivity slide down, here's the code:

```
 Button BackToMainActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ToMainActivity);
    BackToMainActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);


  // overridePendingTransition( 0, R.anim.animate_down);  
  overridePendingTransition( R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.animate_down);

        }

    });
```

This transition is supposed to work. Instead what it does is it reveals the MainActivity like it's supposed to but the GroupsPage transition animates down but very quickly, barely visible transition, that's how fast.

Here's the animation transition code:

animate_up.xml:

```
android:fromYDelta="100%p"
android:toYDelta="0"
android:duration="600"
```

animate_down.xml:

```
android:fromYDelta="0"
android:toYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="600"
```

no_anim.xml:

```
android:fromXDelta="0"
android:toXDelta="0"
android:duration="500"
```

================================================================

```
 overridePendingTransition( R.anim.animate_up, R.anim.animate_down);
```

When I add animate_up with animate_down. Here, the animate_down code now works and it animates down fine. But the MainActivity screen also animates up now, which I don't need.

```
overridePendingTransition( 0, R.anim.animate_down);
overridePendingTransition( R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.animate_down);
```

Now in the 2 codes above, animate_down does NOT work, it's a strange incredibly fast moving animation that's barely visible. How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an interpolator can help:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="600" />
</set>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html